# Equivalence between $(a_n)$ being Cauchy and the hypothesis that $|a_{n+2} - 2a_{n-1} + a_n|\to0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

*(a)* Prove that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|a_{n+2} - 2a_{n-1} + a_n|<\epsilon$

*(b)* Is the converse true? Why or why not?

So for *(a)* I have

$|a_{n+2} - 2a_{n-1} + a_n|=|a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}+a_n| \leq $ $|a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}|+|a_n-a_{n-1}|$

Let $|a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a_n-a_{n-1}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then it follows that $|a_{n+2} - 2a_{n-1} + a_n|\leq$ $|a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}|+|a_n-a_{n-1}| <\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon $

for *(b)* I'm having a bit of trouble.
The converse is *(I think)*

$\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$  $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $|a_{n+2} - 2a_{n-1} + a_n|<\epsilon$

I don't think it is true, and the only way I can think of making some sort of proof is by contradiction. This is as far as I've made it with this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need a "for all $n\ge N$" some where?

Comment: No, the converse this (horribly written) text is alluding to is whether the hypothesis ($\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$, $|a_{n+2} - 2a_{n-1} + a_n|<\epsilon$) implies that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: I think by "converse", it is asking you to show whether $ (a) $ implies that $(a_n)_n $ is Cauchy.

Comment: @Rise Yes, you are right. I  copied it down just as the professor put it on the board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(b) is false, the sequence $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,…$ is clearly not Cauchy but $|a_n-2a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}|=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Why? If that quantity is always 0, then clearly it's less than $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: The goal was to find a sequence that satisfies (a) but is not Cauchy

Comment: I was answering to a comment that is already deleted.